# Override Django (DRF) Serializer object GET

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to "inject" some `raw sql` into my DRF nested Serializer:

```py
# SERIALIZERS

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'

class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer()   # <--- here I don't want to get the Car object but rather inject a raw sql.

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = '__all__'
```

The SQL injection is needed to request for a specific version of the data since I'm using MariaDB versioning tables but this is not relevant. How do I override the method that gets the object from `CarSerializer`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers, I managed to make it work although my solution is not as clean as the one suggested from @yvesonline and @iklinak:

I first checked the official DRF documentation on overriding serializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

In particular I was interested in the overriding of the method: `.to_representation(self, instance)` that controls the fetching of the object from the database:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.relations import PKOnlyObject
from rest_framework.fields import SkipField, empty

    def __init__(
            self, instance=None, data=empty, asTime=str(dt.now()), **kwargs):
        self.asTime = asTime
        self.instance = instance
        if data is not empty:
            self.initial_data = data
        self.partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        self._context = kwargs.pop('context', {})
        kwargs.pop('many', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # substitute instance with my raw query
        # WARNING: self.asTime is a custom variable, check the
        # __init__ method above!

        instance = Car.objects.raw(
            '''
                    select * from db_car
                    for system_time as of timestamp %s
                    where id=%s;
                ''', [self.asTime, instance.id])[0]

        ret = OrderedDict()
        fields = self._readable_fields

        for field in fields:
            try:
                attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
            except SkipField:
                continue

            check_for_none = attribute.pk if isinstance(
                attribute, PKOnlyObject) else attribute
            if check_for_none is None:
                ret[field.field_name] = None
            else:
                ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

        return ret
```

*You can find the original code here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/19655edbf782aa1fbdd7f8cd56ff9e0b7786ad3c/rest_framework/serializers.py#L335*

Then finally in the `DriverSerializer` class:

```py
class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(asTime='2021-02-05 14:34:00')

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but I think you want to override the `__init__` in `DriverSerializer` and then load the result of your raw SQL via `data`, something like this:

```
class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     [...]
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(DriverSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          name_map = {'column_1': 'obj_attr_1', 'column_2': 'obj_attr_1', 'pk': 'id'}
          raw = Car.objects.raw('SELECT ... FROM ...', translations=name_map)
          data = {k: getattr(raw[0], k) for k in name_map.keys()}
          self.car = CarSerializer(data=data)
```

Comment: Hi @yvesonline, can you clarify what is the `name_map`? the column is the name of the attribute in the django model and the object? thanks

Comment: It is simply dict mapping of parameters as documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Answer (score 1):

You could define method under your model to get related Car

```
class Car(models.Model):

    def current_car(self):
        return Car.objects.raw('SELECT ... FROM ...')[0]
```

Then in serializer you could reuse following method

```
class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(source="current_car")

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = (...)
```

Comment: Hi @iklinac can I pass an argument to `current_car` method? like in my case the timestamp of the version of the car I want to fetch

Comment: Where does this timestamp come from, is it now?

Comment: well in my case come from another serializer. Let's say it comes from the `DriverSerializer`